# Can a filesystem ever be specified by its mount point?

Tags: filesystems

Is it correct that for an umounted filesystem, the only way to specify it is to specify its underlying partition?

For a mounted filesystem, can we specify it by either specifying its underlying partition or specifying its mount point? In particular, can a filesystem ever be specified by its mount point?

Thanks.

Comment: What Unix are you referring to? Linux only?

Comment: I have never used Unix. I am not sure if it is different in Unix.

Comment: @Tim **Gnu/Linux (e.g. Debian, Ubuntu, Centos, Suse, …) is Unix. However it is not UNIX.** The title for site is miss-leading. (Also Linux is a kernel, not an OS, it can be part of a Unix OS e.g. Gnu/Linux, or a not Unix OS. Gnu is a Unix OS and has many kernels: Linux, Hurd, BSD, cygwin (A MS-Windows dll), LSW (another MS-Windows thing).

Comment: It is unclear what context you are asking. What you are saying about mount-point or partition-device is true of the `umount` command, but will not be true of all commands.

Comment: @ctrl Can you be specific about "What you are saying about mount-point or partition-device is true of the umount command, but will not be true of all commands"? Maybe in a reply?

Comment: Specifically there are commands, that I don't know what they are (for example, I could write one right now) that this will not be true of.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Can you be specific about "What you are saying about mount-point or partition-device is true of the umount command"?

Comment: from `man umount` “umount [-dflnrv] {mount-directory|device}...”

Answer (score 4):

You may also specify an unmounted filesystem by its label or by its UUID. You may have entries like “LABEL=foobar” or “UUID=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000” in your `/etc/fstab`.

As far as I know, that is handled by `udev`: when it discovers a partition, it reads its UUID and LABEL, and add links to the partition in `/dev/disk/by-uuid` and `/dev/disk/by-label`.

The label might contain the mount point, so you can reference the partition by its mount point.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say it in another way.

How can you specify something? You have to uniquely describe it, at least not causing any confusing. A pathname, without context, you can't actually know what is it refering to, could be simply path ,or the device with its device number, or the device node file or the filesystem stored in the device with its device number.

`resize2fs` gets a string from you and interpret it as a pathname of a device file and think you want to resize the filesystem lives on the corresponding device.

While other tools or APIs might not use the same assumption. `chmod` also gets a string from you and interpret it as a pathname of a file, but just change the permission of that inode instead of touching the corresponding device or even the filesystem lives on it. `chmod` doesn't even care about wether it's a device node or not.